# Expected location in a 2D random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random-walk

You have two coins in front of you: red and blue. The blue coin flips a head with probability $\frac{1}{8}$
and the red coin flips a head with probability $\frac{1}{9}$.

• If both coins flip heads, you go north $3$ blocks.

• If blue is heads and red is tails, you go north $1$ block.

• If blue is tails and red is heads, you go east $1$ block.

• If both coins flip tails, you go east $2$ blocks.

What is your expected location after $217$ flips? What is the standard deviation for going north in exactly $1$ flip of both coins?
Assume coin flips are independent for each coin and that both coins are independent. You must use random variables.

Calculating the individual probabilities for the $4$ directions is pretty straightforward. The issue I am facing is the non-homogenous nature of the random walk.  And secondly, how do I go about the $217$ flips. One thing that comes to my mind is using complex numbers, mapping the directions in $2D$ complex plane and each subsequent flip would simply be the multiplication of the difference in coordinates. I am not sure if this would work. Looking for any more leads and/or developments on my idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1$ be the random variable that represents the first step of the walk.
It is equal to $3e_2$ with probability $1/72$, $e_2$ with probability $1/9$, $e_1$ with probability $7/72$, and $2e_1$ with probability $7/9$, where $e_2$ is north and $e_1$ is east.

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{217}$ be iid. We want to know $\mathbb{E}[X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{217}]$. Due to the linearity of expectation, this is equal to
$$\mathbb{E}[X_1] + \mathbb{E}[X_2]+\cdots+\mathbb{E}[X_{217}] = 217\mathbb{E}[X_1].$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: This helps. Thanks. I am able to figure out the expected value from here. Could you just help me with the standard deviation part as well. I am not sure what does it even mean. Thanks

Comment: @unknown2718 What part are you struggling with in that? It's just a routine variance calculation for the random variable $X$ that represents movement along the north direction -- compute $\mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2$.

Comment: How do I calculate $E(X^2)$? Is it straightforward?

Comment: The above answer is excellent. For the variance use the same trick, the $X_i$ are independent therefore Var(Sum) = Sum(Var)

Comment: @BearCakes100 how does sum come into the picture since we are concerned with a single flip of both coins. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: You know $X$, and it seems pretty simple to manually figure out what $X^2$ (and so $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$) is. I think @BearCakes100 interpreted the second part as asking for the variance of the location after $217$ moves, so they remarked that variance is additive for independent random variables.